# Invoke Docker Remote API using Java

Tags: java, apache, rest, docker, jersey

I'm able to query a Docker host using Remote API as:

```
curl https://<IP>:2376/images/json --cert cert.p12 --pass mypass --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem
```

Can anybody help on how to transform this curl REST invocation to any Java library code?

Looked at Jersey and HttpClient libraries but seems like they require extensive setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the [`docker-java` project](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) can help here.

From [one of the test classes](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/command/StartContainerCmdImplTest.java#L71-L77):

```
    Volume volume1 = new Volume("/opt/webapp1");

    Volume volume2 = new Volume("/opt/webapp2");

    CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("busybox").withVolumes(volume1, volume2)
            .withCmd("true").withBinds(new Bind("/src/webapp1", volume1, ro), new Bind("/src/webapp2", volume2))
            .exec();
```

[The Wiki](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki) mentions certificates:

```
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("http://localhost:2375").build();

// Or: Intialize docker client (advanced)

DockerClientConfig config = DockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
  .withUri("https://docker.somewhere.tld:2376")
  .withDockerCertPath("/home/user/.docker")
  .withUsername(registryUser)
  .withPassword(registryPass)
  .withEmail(registryMail)
  .withServerAddress(registryUrl)
  .build();
```

---

As mentioned in [your issue 483](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/483), you either:

- need to use maven and take advantage of the [`pom.xml` dependencies](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/c28e8d564f24150a5c3ea4d1400b70fd9b882822/pom.xml#L80-L226),
- or use a `mvn dependency:list -DincludeScope=runtime` to get the list of all runtime dependencies.

Comment: This did not work https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/483. Any idea?

Comment: @ArunGupta yes: use maven (or m2e in Eclipse) with this library: the list of dependencies is clearly defined in the pom.xml (https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/c28e8d564f24150a5c3ea4d1400b70fd9b882822/pom.xml#L80-L226)

Comment: Would love to use Maven, Gradle or one of those tools. But this is for Minecraft Forge which generates a classic Eclipse project. And so will have to manually fiddle around with these for now.